# iPhone + sqlite3 + fmdb, What code do i need to put data into a UiTableView datasource?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0, fmdb

If I was adding data from an array to the UITableView datasource array I'd use this, in viewDidLoad.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Head First Design Patterns", @"Head First HTML & CSS", @"Head First iPhone", nil];
self.transactionsArray = array;
[array release];
```

And this in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
cell.textLabel.text = [transactionsArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

But I want to link up the results from a select query, I'm using fmdb to access my database. Heres how I output data to the console with fmdb at the moment.

```
FMDatabase* db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"/tmp/mydb.db"];
if (![db open]) {
    NSLog(@"Could not open db.");
}

FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"select * from myTable",  nil];
while ([rs next]) {
    NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@, %@, %@", [rs stringForColumn:@"pid"],
            [rs stringForColumn:@"desc"], 
            [rs stringForColumn:@"due"],
            [rs stringForColumn:@"price"],
            [rs stringForColumn:@"accumulated_price"]);
}
[rs close]; 
[db close];
```

How do i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a transaction array in the while loop like this:

```
[transactionArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[rs stringForColumn@"pid", @"dictionaryLabel",........, nil];
```

EDIT: Yup thats right, to accesses it just use:

```
descLabelInTableView = [[arrayTmp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"desc"];
```

Comment: dictionary label? can you complete your example with my fields ?
Can you also show me what would go in cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: Is this correct ?

  [arrayTmp addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[rs stringForColumn:@"desc"],@"desc",
        [rs stringForColumn:@"due"],@"due", 
        [rs stringForColumn:@"price"],@"price", 
        [rs stringForColumn:@"accumulated_price"],@"accum",nil]];

If so how do I access each item from cellForRowAtIndexPath ?